# border-image-repeat: space not working

Tags: css

I've met a small problem that I cannot seem to solve.

This is my CSS code that should work:

```
div.menu-menu_hun-container li {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    -moz-border-image:url("images/menu-border.png") 0 0 1 0;
    -webkit-border-image:url("images/menu-border.png") 0 0 1 0;
    border-image:url("images/menu-border.png") 0 0 1 0;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-image-repeat: space;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add a border image only to the bottom of each menu element (except the last one as it's already solved). The problem is that the space property doesn't work at all. Menu elements are 187px width and the image is 125px. I want to position the border element to the left to cover 2/3 of the bottom line. Perhaps, I do not understand how this property works, but I think it should position a single image element to the center of the bottom border because there's no more space left for another image element to make the border complete. I hope you guys could clear the mess in my head.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide fiddle or image, it will be nice, anyway, Try to re-size the image and use `border-image-repeat: space;` or you can use `round` property.